# Firebase custom parameter type text is gone, how do I record it now?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase used to have custom parameter type text to record individual info like this

[image]

But now Firebase has updated and I can't find any way to record text parameters anymore, only number parameters are recorded. The button "Edit parameter reporting" is gone, and now the function has moved to the "Manage Custom Definition" which has the "Custom dimensions" tab and "Custom metrics" tab. I don't know what "Custom dimensions" is for, "Custom metrics" is only for registering number parameter.

Is the feature to record text parameter gone? If not, how do I record text parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same. Firebase recently deprecated the custom parameter reporting and replaced it with the [event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209).

Prior to the rollout, you need to register the parameter per event. Now, you only need to register the parameter in the "Manage Custom Definition" once, and you will see a report for each event that will log the parameter.

- Custom dimensions are your event parameters with text value.
- Custom metrics are your event parameters with numeric value.

Comment: So I used this code to log parameter with text value:  FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(string name, string paramName, int value); This code used to log to Firebase with parameter registered as text value successfully. I assume now I need to convert the value to string first for Firebase to recognize my value as text?

Comment: To prevent any issues in the future, I suggest you use the same data type when you register the parameter and log the event.